# Xpage Calendar entries not visible in Production server

Tags: calendar, xpages

I tested a calendar view in development server, it is working fine and i'm able to see the entries in calendar as i wanted but after moving to Production server I'm getting empty calendar view with no entries .

Can anyone one suggest what could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the Calendar View control, compare and contrast the REST service, the underlying View design element, ?ReadViewEntries for the calendar view. I'm assuming the calendar view is in the same database as the XPage, so best to confirm if that's not the case.